# Is it possible to inject CSS in an external browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, visual-studio

My main goal is to create a way to customize and save Twitch.TV Chat Styles for streamers to stream their chat. I created a C# WinForm in Visual Studio and planned to use its WebBrowser element and use C# to edit the CSS inside of it but turns out Twitch's Chat doesn't work in the WebBrowser which is weird because it works in Internet Explorer. Anyways my second option was to have custom nobs and dials to customize the users CSS and then a "Update" button which would allow the injection of the CSS into the browser's chat window.

I've looked everywhere and I guess I am searching for the wrong terms or it's not possible without some DLL's or something. My last option if this doesn't work is to create a greasemonkey script with UI in the chatroom but I really don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating your own local css files and starting at the top with an import of the other site's css files?

You can then override everything locally.

[Import described here in detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

Comment: I want it to be user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is via a [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), which is essentially a browser bookmark that, instead of containing a link, contains some JavaScript that gets executed on click.

Here's an example:

```js
javascript: (function () { var styleEl = document.getElementById('injected-css'); if (styleEl) { styleEl.remove(); return; } styleEl = document.createElement('style'); styleEl.id = 'injected-css'; styleEl.innerHTML = 'body { background-color: green }'; document.body.append(styleEl); })();
```

Save this string as a bookmark and then click on it, and you should see the body's background color turning green.